# Resolving XXE for Oracle DomParser

Tags: java, xml, security, xml-parsing, xxe

Here is the code snippet for a DomParser which I am using, The DomParser which I am using is of Oracle.

```
import oracle.xml.parser.v2.DOMParser;

DOMParser domParser = new DOMParser();      
domParser.parse(new StringReader(xmlPayload));    
Document doc = domParser.getDocument();

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");
```

Recently our Security team has raised a concern that the above DOM parser is vulnerable to security attack and has come up with a recommendation on setting two attributes

```
domParser.setAttribute("RESOLVE_ENTITY_DEFAULT", true);
domParser.setAttribute("DEFAULT_ENTITY_EXPANSION_DEPTH", 150);
```

But on setting these attributes, I am getting the below error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.setAttribute(XMLParser.java:870)
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.DOMParser.setAttribute(DOMParser.java:538)
at DomParserExample.main(DomParserExample.java:20)
```

kindly let me know how can I prevent XML Entity Expansion injection and XXE attacks.  I have tried looking into  OWASP XEE Cheat Sheet and browsed through various questions and answers for XXE attack, but could not find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
domParser.setAttribute(XMLParser.RESOLVE_ENTITY_DEFAULT, true);
domParser.setAttribute(XMLParser.DEFAULT_ENTITY_EXPANSION_DEPTH, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle XXE in Oracle DOMParser is documented here.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adxdk/security-considerations-oracle-xml-developers-kit.html#GUID-45303542-41DE-4455-93B3-854A826EF8BB

```
    // Extend oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser
    DOMParser domParser = new DOMParser(); 

    // Do not expand entity references
    domParser.setAttribute(DOMParser.EXPAND_ENTITYREF, false);

    // dtdObj is an instance of oracle.xml.parser.v2.DTD
    domParser.setAttribute(DOMParser.DTD_OBJECT, dtdObj);

    // Do not allow more than 11 levels of entity expansion
    domParser.setAttribute(DOMParser.ENTITY_EXPANSION_DEPTH, 12);
```

Answer (score -1):

what will be the maven dependencies version to use XMLParser and DOMParser to get resolve the fortify fix for DOM Parser.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for similar questions, or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)